# How to display multiple images from database in Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am stuck with some code. So I fetch the Images data the database now when I try to load the image on the blade file it is not finding the image, and if I put the direct url in the address bar it says 404 not found. Below is the code.

Controller File Code

```
public function displayReferenceImages($document_id){
    $is_ref_imgs_exist = Document::select('reference_images')->where('document_id', $document_id)->get();
    if(count($is_ref_imgs_exist)>0) {
        $reponse = $is_ref_imgs_exist[0]->reference_images;
        return view('testfile')->with(['sliders' => $reponse]);
    }else{
        return "No image found";
    }
}
```

So the response is like this :

**public/HRTKD1607941923/HRTKDRI16079419230.jpg,public/HRTKD1607941923/HRTKDRI16079419231.jpg,public/HRTKD1607941923/HRTKDRI16079419242.jpg,**

Blade File Code :

```
@foreach (explode(',', $sliders) as $image)
<img src="{{ URL::to('storage/app/'.$image)}}">
@endforeach
```

Now it is not showing.

Before this I use a code to display single image :
That is :

```
public function displayImage($document_id)
{
    $is_cover_image_exist = Document::select('cover_image')->where('document_id', $document_id)->get();
    if(count($is_cover_image_exist)>0) {
        $temp_file_name = $is_cover_image_exist[0]->cover_image;
        $content = Storage::get($temp_file_name);
        $mime = Storage::mimeType($temp_file_name);
        $response = Response::make($content, 200);
        $response->header("Content-Type", $mime);
        return $response;
    }else{
        $content = Storage::get('public/default.jpg');
        $mime = Storage::mimeType('public/default.jpg');
        $response = Response::make($content, 200);
        $response->header("Content-Type", $mime);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

and In blade file :

```
<img src="{{ route('load_image',$suggestion->document_id) }}" class="img-fluid rounded" alt="">
```

I also Tried this but no success.

Comment: please provide the desired url for all the image, location of your images(is it in public folder)

Comment: No, its on the under storage/app/public folder

Comment: try to store it in public folder like `public/assets/images` then you can access it directly without the help of going to the controller `<img src={{url('/assets/images/<!--photo.type-->')}} width="" height="" alt=""/>`

Comment: Have you tried assets yet? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-asset

Comment: None of them is working until I use **Storage->url();** to generate a url then it worked. Don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Just a info. Instead of these methods just try to use Laravel media library plugin. Which is really helpful for a scenario like this. https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v9/introduction

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach($images as $image)
        <?php foreach (json_decode($image->image_path) as $picture) { ?>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 col-md-6 mb-3">
                <img src="uploads/{{$picture}}" alt="{{$picture}}">
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
@endforeach
```